# Brining back value that matches a number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to bring back a specific value from my worksheets

Worksheet 1:
[Worksheet with columns Survey_ID and Credit Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyxIi.jpg)

Worksheet 2:
[Worksheet with Columns PII_ID, Survey_ID, Name, Credit Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbqqu.jpg)

**Objective**

1. Use Survey ID from Worksheet 1 (in this case 7)
2. Return "1" if
         PII_ID = 17 where Survey_ID = 7
         **OR** Column F =1 where Survey_ID = 7

Problems encountered:
So far i have tried using a Vlookup to bring back value from Column F using the survey ID. In this case, Vlookup looks at the first value, which in this case is blank. In another record where i only have 1 value beside it, it retrieves properly

**Ask**

How can look at the array of survey ID's and their respect PII_ID's and retrieve a 1 if the PII_ID = 17?

Comment: "Return "1" if PII_ID = 17 where Survey_ID = 7 OR Column F =1 where Survey_ID = 7" -- Maybe I'm not following the logic properly, but for both cases, you would get `1` as a result.

Comment: Correct , I want to return 1 using either scenario. The problem i am having is returning 1 into Worksheet 1. So for example i would want 1 returned into column L if the PII_ID = 17 for Survey_ID = 7. When i use a Vlookup it looks at the first row where Survey ID =7 (in worksheet 2). In that case the PII_ID = 2 matchs the first value.

Comment: If you want to return `1` using either scenario, just return `1` if `Survey_ID = 7`, no need for the `Or`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not very clearly about your problem with conditions. Could your provide the logic more clearly?